# proper expand command line parameter in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I want to display what I'm running, but when the commands contain space parameter, it failed.

```
#!/bin/bash
go() {
  echo "*** $*"
  $* || exit 1
}
go make NAME="Hi Here"
```

That will get wrong behavior like

```
make NAME=Hi Here
```

Is there any better method to improve the go() function?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? What is the real goal ? What is the context ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace $* with "$@":

```
#!/bin/bash
go() {
  echo "*** $*"
  "$@" || exit 1
}
go make NAME="Hi Here"
```